# What is the best way to dynamically fill values in SQL based on conditions from other columns from previous rows?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

This is a problem I would normally do in python, but wanted to see if it could be done efficiently in SQL.

I have a sample forecasted sales dataset that looks like this:

| item | location_id | forecast | week_begin | pack_size | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 1.43 | 12/3/23 | 6 | 1 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 2.67 | 12/10/23 | 6 | 2 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 0.82 | 12/17/23 | 6 | 3 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 1.23 | 12/24/23 | 6 | 4 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 1.23 | 12/31/23 | 6 | 5 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 1.23 | 1/7/24 | 6 | 6 |
| blue_marker | 999 | 4.31 | 12/3/23 | 6 | 1 |
| blue_marker | 999 | 6.47 | 12/10/23 | 6 | 2 |
| blue_marker | 999 | 6.47 | 12/17/23 | 6 | 3 |
| blue_marker | 999 | 6.47 | 12/24/23 | 6 | 4 |
| blue_marker | 999 | 6.47 | 12/31/23 | 6 | 5 |
| blue_marker | 999 | 6.47 | 1/7/24 | 6 | 6 |

The data is the forecasted sales units for the next 6 weeks for different items going to different stores. A row number has already been added to each item / location / week. The `pack_size` columns is how many units get sent to the store when inventory is needed.

The goal is to create two columns `units_to_store` and `week_end_inventory` to determine when a store should be sent a pack of an item based on the forecasted sales. The ideal final state dataset is below (just for green_pencil, but would want it for every item / store combo):

| item | location_id | forecast | week_begin | pack_size | row_number | units_to_store | week_end_inventory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 1.43 | 12/3/23 | 6 | 1 | 6 | 4.57 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 2.67 | 12/10/23 | 6 | 2 | 0 | 1.9 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 0.82 | 12/17/23 | 6 | 3 | 0 | 1.08 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 1.23 | 12/24/23 | 6 | 4 | 6 | -0.15 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 1.23 | 12/31/23 | 6 | 5 | 0 | 4.77 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 1.23 | 1/7/24 | 6 | 6 | 0 | 3.54 |

The first week will always start with the items `pack_size` in this case, 6 units. Then the goal is to take the forecasted sales and have a running sum until that number gets below 0, in which a new pack should be sent to the stores and the running sum starts again with the `pack_size`. The `week_end_inventory` for the first week will be the `pack_size` - `forecast` and then the `forecast` will be subtracted in the next rows / weeks until it gets below 0 and the process will start over again.

What is the best way to do this? I have tried to use the `lag` function but have trouble with the need for a dynamically filled values.

Comment: Side note: You might already know this, but you should know SQL SELECT statements are not guaranteed to return rows in any order except what is specified in ORDER BY.  You must not assume rows are returned in row ID or date order unless you add the ORDER BY to make them.

Comment: so you have a database in mysql and postgres and presto - how weird. **Please ONLY tag the ONE database that is relevant** to your question. Each of those databases has a different syntax in their implementation of SQL - we need to know the correct one.

Comment: changed to presto / trino only. thanks.

Comment: How `forecast` of `0.82` in the first row for `green_pencil` became `1.43` in the result?

Comment: Also can `pack_size` change for the same item?

Comment: ```pack_size``` will never change, apologizes there was a pasting issue that has been resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a revised answer (using Postgres, but should work in Presto)

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
      item VARCHAR(200)
    , location_id INTEGER
    , forecast DECIMAL(10, 2)
    , week_begin DATE
    , pack_size INTEGER
    , row_number INTEGER
    );

INSERT INTO mytable (item, location_id, forecast, week_begin, pack_size, row_number) 
VALUES 
('green_pencil', 1234, 0.82, '2023-12-03', 6, 1),
('green_pencil', 1234, 0.82, '2023-12-10', 6, 2),
('green_pencil', 1234, 0.82, '2023-12-17', 6, 3),
('green_pencil', 1234, 1.23, '2023-12-24', 6, 4),
('green_pencil', 1234, 1.23, '2023-12-31', 6, 5),
('green_pencil', 1234, 1.23, '2024-01-07', 6, 6),
('blue_marker', 999, 4.31, '2023-12-03', 6, 1),
('blue_marker', 999, 6.47, '2023-12-10', 6, 2),
('blue_marker', 999, 6.47, '2023-12-17', 6, 3),
('blue_marker', 999, 6.47, '2023-12-24', 6, 4),
('blue_marker', 999, 6.47, '2023-12-31', 6, 5),
('blue_marker', 999, 6.47, '2024-01-07', 6, 6);
```

**Query:** Here I calculate units_to_store based on a simple running sum of forecast, then in the final query week_end_inventory is calculated from the running sum of units_to_store.

```
with inventory as (
    SELECT item
        , location_id
        , forecast
        , week_begin
        , pack_size
        , row_number
        , SUM(forecast) OVER (
            PARTITION BY item, location_id 
            ORDER BY week_begin ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
            ) AS run_forecast
       , case 
            when row_number = 1 then pack_size
            when SUM(forecast) OVER (
                PARTITION BY item, location_id 
                ORDER BY week_begin ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                )  / pack_size > 1 then pack_size 
            else 0
        end as units_to_store
    FROM mytable
    )
select
   item, location_id, week_begin, pack_size, forecast, units_to_store
  , sum(units_to_store) OVER (
            PARTITION BY item, location_id 
            ORDER BY week_begin ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
            ) - run_forecast AS week_end_inventory
  , row_number, run_forecast
from inventory
```

| item | location_id | week_begin | pack_size | forecast | units_to_store | week_end_inventory | row_number | run_forecast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blue_marker | 999 | 2023-12-03 | 6 | 4.31 | 6 | 1.69 | 1 | 4.31 |
| blue_marker | 999 | 2023-12-10 | 6 | 6.47 | 6 | 1.22 | 2 | 10.78 |
| blue_marker | 999 | 2023-12-17 | 6 | 6.47 | 6 | 0.75 | 3 | 17.25 |
| blue_marker | 999 | 2023-12-24 | 6 | 6.47 | 6 | 0.28 | 4 | 23.72 |
| blue_marker | 999 | 2023-12-31 | 6 | 6.47 | 6 | -0.19 | 5 | 30.19 |
| blue_marker | 999 | 2024-01-07 | 6 | 6.47 | 6 | -0.66 | 6 | 36.66 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 2023-12-03 | 6 | 0.82 | 6 | 5.18 | 1 | 0.82 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 2023-12-10 | 6 | 0.82 | 0 | 4.36 | 2 | 1.64 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 2023-12-17 | 6 | 0.82 | 0 | 3.54 | 3 | 2.46 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 2023-12-24 | 6 | 1.23 | 0 | 2.31 | 4 | 3.69 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 2023-12-31 | 6 | 1.23 | 0 | 1.08 | 5 | 4.92 |
| green_pencil | 1234 | 2024-01-07 | 6 | 1.23 | 6 | 5.85 | 6 | 6.15 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kQJ02QOz)

---

Original (and only partial) approach (assumed MySQL)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D0b1ZIQb)

Comment: This is a good start but this was the issue I was having. I need to have the LAG function account for the new value that will be entered, but am having trouble writing it out efficiently. I could do like 5 different views / CTEs but would want to avoid that if possible. Thanks for the quick comment!

Comment: CTEs are no less efficient if you use then correctly and filter data as you go rather than getting all data in each CTE and then filtering at the end and it makes the code readability better.

Comment: comments above relate to an original (partial) response, subsequently updated.